# How do I remove a package from Package Control but not uninstall it for current users?

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I have a ST3 package hosted on GitHub and available through Package Control. It has been superseded by a new package that I wrote, but I keep getting bug reports for the old one since many people are still using it.

What is the correct way to remove the option to install the original package from package control, and ideally from GitHub if possible, without messing anything up for users who currently have the old package installed?

Specifically, will submitting a pull request to Package Control to remove the old package, and/or deleting the old package's github repo, cause the old package to disappear from people's Sublime Text?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest reading through the [package developer docs](https://packagecontrol.io/docs#Package_Developers), especially the section entitled [Renaming a Package](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/renaming_a_package), as they explain everything in detail. Essentially, the easiest path would be to following the directions for renaming a package, and at the same time change the URL to your new Github repo. This way, the old packagecontrol.io page will no longer be available, and upon restart users of the old package *should* be upgraded to the new one.

I'd also recommend reading through the Package Control Channel's [issues](https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue) to see if this issue has come up before. Worst case scenario, you submit your PR and it gets rejected for some reason, but they'll explain what you need to do differently.

Comment: I should clarify that I don't want to automatically upgrade the users of the old package, which might upset them or break if their ST version is too low. The new package also has a different name. I basically want to know if a pull request to Package Control to delete the package, plus deleting the github repository, will result in the package being deleted from people's systems (which I don't want)

Comment: @user2664470 No, it will not. The only issue people will run into is if they set up Sublime on a new computer and try to reinstall the same packages. But, why delete the Github repo? Why not just leave it for people that want to install manually?